# How to set value to span attribute using WebClient C#

Tags: c#, html-parsing, webclient, html-agility-pack

I am parsing site using ***HtmlAgilityPack*** and ***WebClient***. And there is a part of site structure:

```html
<div is-static-condition="True" class="logic-group-condition">
   <span class="condition-field  condition-field-locked" field 
        name="tbAuctionObjects_flObjectType">Object type</span>
   <span class="condition-operator " operator="In">Included in</span>
   <span class="condition-value" value="" title="" full-text="[Not specified]">
        [Not specified]</span>
   <span class="condition-clear">Clear</span>
</div>
```

I need to set different values to "value" attribute (for example "1") and submit POST request to server. How to do this? The site is [need parse this site](https://e-auction.gosreestr.kz/p/). I tried to use ***NameValueCollection*** class, but it didn't help me, because there are no input elements with id attribute

Comment: Why do you need to set different value to `value`? You can't trigger a button using HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: I want to parse this site - when i change value, the data in table filtered. That's why i can categorize objects.